# Why my robots.txt is not honored by Google?

Tags: robots.txt

This is my `robots.txt`.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /property/
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

As you can see, I have disallowed the `/property/` path. Yet I see some of the links on my website that have this path segment and are indexed.
For example:

```
      https://example.com/property/153    
      https://example.com/property/8923
```

Why does Google not honor this file?

Comment: Were the URLs indexed before you added that line to robots.txt? That could explain why they're still indexed.

Comment: @Pete, I don't know that. Maybe they were indexed before. But one would expect the Google to update its index based on the new content of the `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the following article, while it's likely that blocking Google from crawling a page will remove it from index, it's not a guarantee.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots-faq#h17

> However, robots.txt disallow does not guarantee that a page will not appear in results: Google may still decide, based on external information such as incoming links, that it is relevant and show the URL in the results. If you wish to explicitly block a page from being indexed, use the noindex robots meta tag or X-Robots-Tag HTTP header. In this case, don't disallow the page in robots.txt, because the page must be crawled in order for the tag to be seen and obeyed.

You can wait and see if the pages are de-indexed over time. Otherwise, there are further ways to [control what you share on Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/control-what-you-share).

Answer (score 2):

That signifies it will no longer crawl it, but the crawled versions still exist unless you assign a `noindex` meta tag. You should remove that from your `robots.txt` and instead apply this meta tag to all those pages.

Once those pages have been removed you can re-add it to `robots.txt`, but to be safe continue adding the meta tag.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing

Comment: The first part is not true.  If there are external links to a page, then robots.txt may get ignored.

Comment: Rather than allowing Google to crawl those pages and rely on a noindex tag you could perform a manual removal through Search Console to remove them from the index and rely on the robots.txt/meta directives to prevent future crawling and indexing.